# spring elasticsearch : how to save Map as string in index?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

i'm facing an index issue.
In my Spring document, I have a map. This map can contains thousands of data because I save history.

```
private NavigableMap<String, Integer> installHistory = new TreeMap<>();
```

In elastic search all data in my map are index, and I got a limit exeed error.

[image]

How could I do to not index all data inside the Map ?
I use spring 2.2 and spring elastic search 3.2.4

Thanks in advance.

Edit :
I upgrade to spring data elastic 4.0.1 to use FielType.Flattened, but spring data elastic  4.0.1 supports min version of elasticsearch 7.6.X. My version is 7.4 and I can't change it because it is the latest version provided by aws.

I made the field transient, and created a String property for this Map. Before saving my object i convert the map into list and put it in the String variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map is converted to a JSON object that has the map keys as properties and the map values as values. So you end up storing objects with thousands of properties, [see the Elasticsearch documentation about this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings).

You could declare the type of the *installHistory* with `FieldType.Flattened`

**Edit:**

I missed that you are using Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.x. Support for the *flattened* field type was added in 4.0.

The best thing then would probably be to convert the Map property to a List of Pairs or Tupels, where each Pair contains a key-value pair from the map.

Comment: Thanks. I did something very dirty. I declare my map has transient and created a string version of the map...But i'm going to remove it and keep the flattened solution. Thanks

Comment: I don't have Flattened in the list of FieldType

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these Custom Converters provided in the Documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.conversions